# Why no regex shorthand / predefined character class for floating point?

Tags: regex

I often need to grep through text files containing numerical data.  Thus I find myself constantly copying and pasting the regular expression for floating point numbers.

I am wondering why there is no shorthand or predefined character class-like entity for floating point numbers.  For example, \d is shorthand for digit. Why not have some back-slash sequence (e.g., \p represent a floating point?)

Comment: Likely because different languages represent floating point differently and regexps are not a culture-aware tool, they're a string matching tool. For example: "3.5" in English, would be "3,5" in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there are several floating point formats (some more common than others).  Just in C, there are [as noted in tutorials](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output), f and g formats which can be mistaken for decimal integers (d).  In some applications fixed-point numbers are common, while in others scientific notion prevails.

Answer (score 1):

That is because regex character classes deal with single characters, i.e. `[a-c]` would be either a or b or c. When looking at floating point numbers, you are looking at patterns of characters not individual characters. The is not even a single character class for integers.

`\d` is short hand for `[0-9]` and would match any single digit, and `\d+` would match a string of digits, however these could match texts with strictly speaking you would not expect as integers, e.g. 0001 or 00113 or even 08000234414141

To properly define a pattern that would match floating point numbers would be quite complex, it would definitely take more than a single character class, and as others have noted, there could be many different formats to floating point numbers.